# Errors uploading ios app to AppStore

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, app-store

I was working on a project on an old macbook and then got a new one I copyed and pasted the project and continued to work on it. Now when I want to update the app on appstore I get a series of errors. I tried some of suggestions found online but couldnt get it to work.

There are the errors I got:

```
ERROR ITMS-90171: "Invalid Bundle Structure - The binary file 'MyApp.app/MyApp WatchKit App.app/_WatchKitStub/WK' is not permitted. Your app can't contain standalone executables or libraries, other than the CFBundleExecutable of supported Bundles."
ERROR ITMS-90455: "The Binary you uploaded was invalid."
ERROR ITMS-90499: "Missing Apple Watch Extension. The application 'MyApp.app/MyApp WatchKit App.app' is missing its corresponding Apple Watch Extension."
ERROR ITMS-90508: "Invalid Info.plist value. The value for the key 'DTPlatformName' in bundle MyApp.app/MyApp WatchKit App.app is invalid."
```

Cleaning and rebuilding didn't do the trick.

In my general project settings it states that on Embedded Binaries there is a "MyApp WatchKit Extension.appex"

Anyone encountered the same problem?

Thanks

Comment: this is not related to switching the macbook - maybe you used a beta of xcode at some point?!

Comment: I think I did, you might be right here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`WatchKitSupport/WK` library should not be included inside IPA file.

Go to **Build Phases > Copy Bundle Resources** and remove it from build.

Comment: I only have "MyApp WatchKit App.app" in copy bundle resources, can't find WatchKitSupport/WK...

Comment: Is that what I should remove? "MyApp WatchKit App.app"?

Comment: Yes remove the .app from there - it should not be included into the bundle

Comment: Dude, you are a life saver! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me was to remove the WatchKit extension from the Embedded Binaries (Project -> Main Target -> General), and adding it again.